# TypeScript says a null value isn't assignable but I already check for nullability

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello everyone I'm trying to figure out how to upload a document in React + TypeScript and I have a state with the selected file set up by the onFileChange event listener like so:

```
onFileChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (event !== null && event.target !== null && event.target.files !== null) {
        this.setState({selectedFile: event.target.files[0]});
    }
};
```

And so far that works, but when I construct the FormData object it errors out.

```
if (this.state !== null && this.state.selectedFile !== null) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append(
            "foo",
            this.state.selectedFile,
            this.state.selectedFile.name
        );
    }
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'
```

I figured I already had checked for nullability for `this.state.selectedFile` and `this.state`. Any reason why this isn't working? Am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: Aside from your question, I note that `event.target.files` could still have `.length == 0`. AFAIK, TypeScript's flow-analysis still doesn't consider array lengths.

Comment: What is the declared type of `this.state.selectedFile`? Do you have strict nulls on or off?

Comment: I don't have a declared type for it I initialised my state like so

```    state = {
        selectedFile: null
    };```

Comment: I do have strict null check turned on

Comment: "I initialised my state like so `state = { selectedFile: null };`" - **that's the problem**. Give your initial state a better type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I initialized my state like so `state = { selectedFile: null };`"

Without an explicit type annotation, TypeScript infers the static-type from its initial value, so TypeScript thinks that your `selectedFile` property can *only* ever be `null`.

A solution is to initialize your state with a wider type annotation, like this:

```
state = {
    selectedFile: null as File | null
};
```

or like this:

```
state: { selectedFile: File | null } = {
    selectedFile: null
};
```

or like this:

```
type MyStateType = { selectedFile: File | null };

state: MyStateType = {
    selectedFile: null
};
```

or like this:

```
interface MyStateType {
    readonly selectedFile: File | null // <-- React state is meant to be immutable so the `readonly` keyword is correct, but you might have issues in the rest of your codebase
}

state: MyStateType = {
    selectedFile: null
};
```